# What do I miss if I buy Monster Hunter: World late?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Recently I have tried Monster Hunter: World on my friend's PS4 and am really hooked on it. I am planning to buy the PC version yet I noticed (at least in the PS4 version) that there are many *time limited events* ending in the past e.g. the recent Witcher collaboration.

Am I missing out something important if I start playing the MH:W PC version now or later? If so, what would I miss? Ultimately, would this impact my game experience?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You won't miss anything whatsoever, if you're willing to play long enough.

The time limited events you mention are a set of quests that periodically rotate in and out of availability, according to [this schedule](http://game.capcom.com/world/steam/uk/schedule.html?utc=1). New event quests are still being added to the PC version, while older event quests are made playable after their original release.

In addition, every event quest is made available during time-limited festivals, lasting 3 or 4 weeks during certain parts of the year. The next such festival is [the Spring Blossom Fest, which is coming on April 26](https://steamcommunity.com/games/582010/announcements/detail/3750844841661514452).

Comment: So the Witcher event will also return?

Comment: @Nzall Yes and no. On PC, the Witcher collaboration event hasn't happened yet. On consoles, there are two parts two the Witcher collaboration: a single-player quest permanently added to the base game, and a rotating, multiplayer event quest that will come back in the future. Nothing is missed by starting to play now in either case.

Comment: As of May/2020, PC and console versions are on par, and nothing is missed. Limited events, as previously answered, keep coming back during holidays and the likes.